# The convexity of convex function's range

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Given a convex function $f\colon X \to \mathbb R$ with convex domain $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, is the range of $f$ a convex set also?

Answer (score 3):

Let $X = [0,1]$ and let $f:X \to \mathbb R$ such that
\begin{equation}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if } x = 0 \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then $f$ is convex, but the range of $f$ is $\{0,1\}$ which is not convex.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What if f is continous and convex function. is the range of function f convex set?

Comment: Assume that $X$ is convex and $f$ is continuous.  Then $X$ is connected (any convex set is connected).  There is a theorem that the continuous image of a connected set is connected.  So the range of $f$ is connected.  Any connected subset of $\mathbb R$ is convex, so the range of $f$ is convex.  Note that this argument does not require $f$ to be convex.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It helps me a lot.